# error partial for multiple models Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial that I use to show errors from an object onto a form.

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>Oops, looks like  <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
             occured:</h2>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <% object.errors.each do |key, msg| %>
                    <li><%=key%><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

It works great for 1 model.

However I can't figure out how to make it work for a form that has two models.

Any ideas? I don't want to use the plugin I would like to have more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just output the partial for each model in the form view with 2 models and pass actual model instances into this partial as local variable:

```
<%= render :partial => 'name_of_partial_to_show_model_errors', :locals => {:object => @model1} %>
<%= render :partial => 'name_of_partial_to_show_model_errors', :locals => {:object => @model2} %>
```